# AS3 Multidimensional array sorting

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to sort a multidimensional array. I want to sort it by the second dimension.

so for example.....

```
    array[0][1] = 5
    array[1][1] = 20
    array[2][1] = 10
```

And I want the output to be 5 , 10 , 20

I tired a few experiments with little / no success. e.g.

```
array.sortOn("1", 0, Array.NUMERIC);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you can use a custom sort function http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sort()

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [custom sort function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sort())

```
var myArray = [[0,5],[0,20],[0,10]];
var sorted = myArray.sort(function(a:Array,b:Array):Number{
    return a[1] - b[1];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second argument is a 0, it should be your array options. Example:

```
var array:Array = [
    [1, 100],
    [2, 50],
    [3, 75]
]

array.sortOn("1", Array.NUMERIC)
trace(array.join("\n"))

array.sortOn("0", Array.NUMERIC);
trace(array.join("\n"))
```

Results:

```
2,50
3,75
1,100

1,100
2,50
3,75
```